# Multiple conditions for result filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects that I am filtering through based on a query. If the query matches a title inside the array of objects I return it.

```
  const arr = [{ title: 'Xbox one controller' }];

  const filterResults = arr.filter((item) =>
    item.title.toLowerCase().includes(req.query.q.toLowerCase())
  );

  res.send(filterResults);
```

These words if I just search on a word like "xbox", however, if I search "xbox controller" it returns nothing.

I was thinking of splitting req.query like this: `const reqy = req.query.q.split(' ')` and using those as keywords although I don't really know where to start. Another potential problem with my "solution" is that if a query looks like "Controller for Xbox One" will the result even show up?

My problem is making the filter function accept multiple "keywords" derived from the user query.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Comment: Look at [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Comment: @SebastianSimon I have, the problem I found is that they only return boolean values and I'm unable to return the actual result

Comment: Yes, they return booleans, and `filter` works well with booleans. Use them inside `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to check whether every word in your search term occurs in the title.  You can call the `split` method on your searchTerm to get an array of words in the search term.  Then call the `every` method to verify whether all of the words in the search term appear in the title.  As before, you can still use the `filter` method to remove those entries whose titles do not contain all of the words in the search term.

```js
const searchTerm = 'xbox controller';

const arr = [{ title: 'Xbox one controller' }];

const filterResults = arr.filter(({ title }) =>
  searchTerm
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(' ')
    .every(keyword => title.toLowerCase().includes(keyword))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` & `some` (or `every` if you want all words are matched)  to achieve your expected result.

- [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp): Split a string into an array of substrings:
- [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some): The some() method tests whether **at least one element in the array passes** the test implemented by the provided function
- [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every): The every() method tests **whether all elements in the array pass** the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

  ```js
  const arr = [{ title: 'Xbox one controller' }];

  const query = 'xbox controller2';
  const splitedQuery = query.split(' ');

  const filterResults = arr.filter(item => {
    let splitedTitle = item.title.split(' ');
    return splitedTitle.some(r => splitedQuery.some(q => r.toLowerCase() == q.toLowerCase()));
  });

  console.log(filterResults);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. Here is one example for you.

```js
const arr = [{ title: 'Xbox one controller' }];
const req = { query: { q: 'Xbox controller' } }

  const filterResults = arr.filter((item) => {
   const queries = req.query.q.split(' ');
   return queries.find((text) => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
  });
  
  console.log(filterResults)
```